# not able to import pickle file in flask

Tags: flask

i am creating a flask app. An erro is shown in the line with code `import pickle`

Error shown is as below

> d:\PROJECTS\Boston-House-Pricing-Prediction-\env\Lib\pickle.py" is overriding the stdlib module "pickle

below is the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,app,jsonify

import pickle    

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
# Load the model
regmodel=pickle.load(open('regmodel.pkl','rb'))
scalar=  pickle.load(open('scalarmodel.pkl' ,'rb'))

@app.route("/") 
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict_api',methods=['POST'])
def predict_api():
    data=request.json(['data'])
    print(data)
    print(np.array(list(data.values())).reshape(1,-1))
    new_data=scalar.transform(np.array(list(data.values())).reshape(1,-1))
    output=regmodel.prediction(new_data)
    print(output[0])
    return jsonify(output[0])


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I read some articles. But nowhere it is mentioned what to do.